# Loading a 3D image and patchifying it on the fly in a DataLoader (Keras)

Tags: keras

I'm currently trying to train a network with dozens of 3D images. But, these images can't fit in the memory at once that's why I chose to use a pipeline (tf.keras.sequence). This pipeline helps me load he images sequentially. What i want to do next is to patchify these images into patches of size 128x128x128, and I want to do it on the fly, meaning that i want to load an image, divide it to patches and then feed it to the model.
Is there a way in Keras to do this?

PS: I don't want to write the patches to the disk, I wan't to do the patchifying on the fly.

Comment: i hope you figured it out, i just started worked on similar problem. if you found solution please share it. it would help many people in future.

Comment: I solved the problem by first passing throught all the images in my dataset, and for every image I saved the voxel coordinates of the beginning and the end of every patch.
I stored this information in a dictionnary as follows key = patch number and value = (voxel coordiantes,  images name).
The next step is to construct a tensorflow generator that takes the patch number as the argument, the generator with load the right image and output the patch with the corresponding coordiantes in the dictionnary.
I hope that you understood my  solution.

Comment: I found that, based on this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mbX4cNGQDk in minute 15, a potential solution is img_patches = patchify(image, (64, 64, 64), step= 64). Hope it helps. I am working on the same type of data and I am trying to use a similar approach.

Comment: The problem with patchify is that it extracts all the patches at once. Which saturates memory. The solution I found in Keras is the one in the comment above, which is to store coordinates of patches in a list. Then iterate over this list and extract the corresponding patches.
There are other solutions already implemented that use the DataLoaders in PyTorch.